# How to do Ad-Hoc deployment of ipa file to my iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipa

I'm developing for iPhone, and want to test my app. I have created an `.ipa` file using an Ad-Hoc deployment profile. I tried emailing the .ipa to myself, but can't figure out how to actually install it once it reaches my iPhone. How can I get my app installed on the device so I can test it, preferably without requiring a connection via cable?

Comment: This question is not off-topic. It's a precise question about deploying software developed for the iPhone. This is not a concern that regular iOS civilians would have.

Comment: You can use https://buildtry.com

Answer (score 13):

1. connect your iPhone to your Macintosh or Windows machine.
2. launch iTunes.
3. drag your .ipa file into your iTunes library.
4. Sync (and hope there's a provisioning profile associated with the app embedded in it).

Answer (score 10):

upload your `ipa` to [diawi](http://www.diawi.com/) click on send button it will generate a `URL` for you, copy `url` and email to yourself, now open mail in your iPhone click on link it will launch safari click on install .
 Note that to install `ipa` through Diawi you must create `ipa` file with `provisioning profile` and that `provisioning profile` must contain your device `UDID`.

Comment: Awsome ! It works..Otherwise had to wait for Apple to approve IPA's too in testflight..Disappointed with this change. Moreover cannot maintain both the current AppStore version and IPA version of App at same time with Apples iTunesconnect testflight.